# getting color information from surface plot

Tags: matlab

```
spX = linspace(min(x), max(x),200);
spY = linspace(min(y), max(y),200);
[xC,yC] = meshgrid(spX,spY);

zC = bin2mat(x,y,z,xC,yC);
zCi = inpaint_nans(zC);

figure;
surface(xC(1,:),yC(:,1),zC);
shading('interp');
axis equal
```

I would like to get color associated with vertices or faces if I used surf2patch function in matlab

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure what you're looking for...

```
surf_h = findobj(gca, 'Type', 'Surf', 'Tag', []);
CData  = get(surf_h, 'CData');
```